# Background for bright orange button

Tags: interface-design, color-theory

I am designing UI/UX for a mobile app. The brand identity is using this bright orange color so I made the button look like this:

[image]

But I don't know which background color to use for this button. and I don't want the app to look too gloomy with a darker color as background.
How should I choose other good colors that complement a brightly colored button like this?

Comment: Hi @kibou, welcome to GD.SE! I made some edits to your post to help clarify what you are asking. If it no longer reflects what you intended to ask, please feel free to decline the edits I've proposed. Enjoy the site and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

If the client has a color scheme as part of the "brand identity" you mentioned in your question, you might have no choice but to use the colors they've provided. However, if the client has given you the freedom to choose the colors for the UI design, there are some free online tools (see below) you can use to generate schemes off of a base color like the orange your client provided. I prefer to use [Adobe Color CC](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/) since I work primarily in Adobe and it's convenient for my workflow:

[image]

Here are some other generators to check out:

- [Paletton - The Color Scheme Designer](http://paletton.com/#uid=10-0u0kxhvZaFw0g0qFFRfRw0aF)
- [Colorco.de](http://www.colourco.de/)
- [Colordot - A Color Picker for Humans](https://color.hailpixel.com/)
- [Color Supply (2-color scheme generator)](http://colorsupplyyy.com/app/)

Comment: Thank you very much for edited my post. I dont know what going when i got downvotes because everyone dont post anything.
I want to know more about Brand Identity. Based on your post, i can use color like light blue. But, what i get confused is, should i change the button color ? The Orange is primary color, so i think to use that color as background, but idk what to choose for button.

Comment: The color scheme of the product you're working on depends on A) if the client has established branding guidelines or B) does not have guidelines and is flexible enough to let you, the designer, choose supporting colors for them. Consequently, they would be able to answer that question better than I could. As far as the down votes on the post, I'm not going to speculate on why it received them, but you can find a lot of information on posting quality questions/answers in the [Help Center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help).